# Bundle videojs with videojs-ima plugin

Tags: javascript, npm, build, module, gulp

I am trying (already few days) to achieve very simple task: build one javascript file that bundle all necessarily parts to play video with Google IMA ads, but I am still facing some errors (mostly `player.ads is not function`) that are always somehow connected to wrongly registered plugins. I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

EDIT: this issue was [already reported](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/issues/473), but marked as priority 3 and I have not time to wait. I believe that there is another solution.

EDIT2: It seems that guy that reported this issue in link above already come with suitable solution. Now it remains only to try it..if it will work, I post it as an answer.

**Entryfile:**

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
/*jshint -W030 */

let ima_script = document.createElement('script');
ima_script.type = "text/javascript";
ima_script.src = "https://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ima_script);

videojs = require('video.js');
require('videojs-contrib-ads');
require('videojs-ima');
require('videojs-youtube');
require('videojs-contrib-hls');

Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('video'))
    .forEach(videojs);

ima_script.onload = function() {
    google.ima.settings.setLocale('cs');
    let players = videojs.players;
    for (let id in players) {
        (players.hasOwnProperty(id) ? players[id].ima({
            id: id,
            adTagUrl: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=',
            disableFlashAds: true
        }):'');
    }
};
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var babelify    = require('babelify');
var buffer      = require('vinyl-buffer');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var css2js      = require('gulp-css-to-js');
var cssnano     = require('gulp-cssnano');
var del         = require('del');
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var ignore      = require('gulp-ignore');
var jshint      = require('gulp-jshint');
var path        = require('path');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var size        = require('gulp-size');
var mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');

var distPath    = path.join(path.normalize('__dirname/../dist'), '/');

gulp.task('build', function (done) {
  runSequence(
    'clean',
    'lintjs',
    'build-bundle',
    function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.message.red);
      } else {
        console.log('BUILD FINISHED SUCCESSFULLY'.green);
      }
      done(error);
    });
});


gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
  del.sync([distPath], {force: true});
  done();
});


gulp.task('lintjs', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'gulpfile.js',
    'src/**/*.js',
    'build/**/*.js'
  ])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('build-bundle', function () {
  var videoJS = browserify({
      entries: 'src/entryfile.js',
      //debug: true,
      paths: ['./node_modules'],
      cache: {},
      packageCache: {}
    })
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('outputfile.js'))
    .pipe(buffer());

  var videoCss = gulp.src('node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(css2js());

  var imaCss = gulp.src('node_modules/video-ima/dist/videojs.ima.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(css2js());

  return mergeStream(videoCss, imaCss, videoJS)
    .pipe(concat('video.bundle.js'))
    /*
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify({compress: false})) // compress needs to be false otherwise it mess the sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))*/
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath))
    .pipe(size({showFiles: true, title: '[VideoJS+Plugin Bundle]'}));
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "videojs-ima-bundle",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "authors": [
    "John Wick <john.wick@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "video.js bundle",
  "main": "src/entryfile.js",
  "repository": {},
  "keywords": [
    "vpaid",
    "html5",
    "vast",
    "videojs",
    "js",
    "video",
    "iab",
    "youtube"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp build"
  },
  "author": "John Wick <john.wick@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "*",
    "babelify": "*",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "browserify-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-css-to-js": "^0.0.2",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-size": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.0",
    "uglifyify": "^3.0.1",
    "video.js": "6.x",
    "videojs-contrib-ads": "*",
    "videojs-contrib-hls": "*",
    "videojs-ima": "^1.0.3",
    "videojs-youtube": "*",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to EDIT2, this is only modification that make it work:

**Modified require part of Entryfile:**

```
videojs = require('video.js');
var contribAds = require('videojs-contrib-ads');
videojs.registerPlugin('ads', contribAds);
require('video.js/dist/lang/cs.js')
require('videojs-youtube');
require('videojs-contrib-hls');
require('videojs-ima');
```

**EDIT**

Registering contrib-ads plugin was "fixed" in v6. Now you should use simply:

```
require('videojs-contrib-ads');
```